# Retrieve emails on behalf of user flow from Hotmail using Microsoft Identity Platform and MSAL.NET

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api, azure-ad-msal, msal.js

All I want is to be able to retrieve emails from Hotmail, I thought it would be very easy.

I have been researched about how to retrieve emails from Hotmail via OAuth and now I reached a dead end.

Here is my preferred architecture:

[image: Architecture]

What I know now is:

1. I need to use Microsoft Graph to retrieve user's emails
2. I need to use OBO(On Behalf Of) flow in my WebApi project to require access token and perform operations

There will be 2 projects:

1 WebApi for handling emails retrieved from Hotmail, Gmail etc.
1 WebApp SPA (React.js) for Web UI

I basically have gone through all related Microsoft documentations (e.g. Microsoft Identity Platform, MSAL.NET) and found these 2 demo projects which I think related to my project:

1. [WebApp calls WebApi to fetch user information. The WebApi calls Microsoft Graph to get emails from Hotmail](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/blob/master/4-WebApp-your-API/4-1-MyOrg/README-incremental-instructions.md)
2. [SPA (JavaScript) web app to call Microsoft Graph](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-javascript-singlepageapp-dotnet-webapi-v2)

On the SPA, when I ran its demo project(I have replaced Application ID in configurations), I found the Demo project only works in Edge (only the sign-in user parts works), it doesn't even work in Firefox.

[image: Not work in FF]

I searched the error message, but got no luck.

I have run out ideas how to make my solution work.

---

Update 1:

I have tried to use this [react + Asp.Net Core project](https://github.com/Odonno/azuread-react-dotnet-core-example) as examples.
I have both asp.net webapi runnint and Reactjs frontend running:
But the reactjs app always show this:
[image]

Here is the url in the address bar for the Reactjs app:

> https://login.microsoftonline.com/02xxxxxxx/oauth2/authorize?response_type=id_token&client_id=02xxxx&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000&state=3b3e49f5-3fff-4249-b3ee-e4f28a87b3dd&client-request-id=2063333f-7dab-4afe-9922-4fe2909ccf37&x-client-SKU=Js&x-client-Ver=1.0.17&nonce=51c7f91f-1c87-4d4b-808b-082433370b39

here is the manifests for both My Asp.Net Core WebApi(Papayee) and the Reactjs client(PapayeeClient)

Papayee:

```
{
    "id": "22xxxx",
    "acceptMappedClaims": null,
    "accessTokenAcceptedVersion": 2,
    "addIns": [],
    "allowPublicClient": false,
    "appId": "28xxx12",
    "appRoles": [],
    "oauth2AllowUrlPathMatching": true,
    "createdDateTime": "2020-04-03T03:59:12Z",
    "groupMembershipClaims": null,
    "identifierUris": [
        "https://papayee008.onmicrosoft.com/papayee008"
    ],
    "informationalUrls": {
        "termsOfService": null,
        "support": null,
        "privacy": null,
        "marketing": null
    },
    "keyCredentials": [],
    "knownClientApplications": [],
    "logoUrl": null,
    "logoutUrl": "https://localhost:44321/signout-oidc",
    "name": "Papayee",
    "oauth2AllowIdTokenImplicitFlow": true,
    "oauth2AllowImplicitFlow": true,
    "oauth2Permissions": [
        {
            "adminConsentDescription": "Allow Papayee to access user's emails for filtering billing emails",
            "adminConsentDisplayName": "Papayee User Impersonation",
            "id": "20xxx7a",
            "isEnabled": true,
            "lang": null,
            "origin": "Application",
            "type": "User",
            "userConsentDescription": "Allow Papayee to access user's emails for filtering billing emails",
            "userConsentDisplayName": "Papayee",
            "value": "user_impersonation"
        },
        {
            "adminConsentDescription": "This is used to retrieve your emails and find your bills",
            "adminConsentDisplayName": "Access Papayee as a user",
            "id": "98xxx15a",
            "isEnabled": true,
            "lang": null,
            "origin": "Application",
            "type": "User",
            "userConsentDescription": "This is used to retrieve your emails and find your bills",
            "userConsentDisplayName": "Access Papayee as a user",
            "value": "access_as_user"
        }
    ],
    "oauth2RequirePostResponse": false,
    "optionalClaims": {
        "idToken": [],
        "accessToken": [],
        "saml2Token": []
    },
    "orgRestrictions": [],
    "parentalControlSettings": {
        "countriesBlockedForMinors": [],
        "legalAgeGroupRule": "Allow"
    },
    "passwordCredentials": [
        {
            "customKeyIdentifier": null,
            "endDate": "2021-04-03T06:44:48.449Z",
            "keyId": "c0xxx110",
            "startDate": "2020-04-03T06:45:01.778Z",
            "value": null,
            "createdOn": "2020-04-03T06:45:10.0053885Z",
            "hint": "7uu",
            "displayName": "papayee"
        }
    ],
    "preAuthorizedApplications": [],
    "publisherDomain": "papayee008.onmicrosoft.com",
    "replyUrlsWithType": [
        {
            "url": "https://localhost:3000",
            "type": "Web"
        },
        {
            "url": "https://localhost:44302/",
            "type": "Web"
        },
        {
            "url": "https://localhost:44302/signin-oidc",
            "type": "Web"
        },
        {
            "url": "https://localhost:44351",
            "type": "Web"
        },
        {
            "url": "http://localhost:5000/",
            "type": "Web"
        },
        {
            "url": "https://localhost:5001/",
            "type": "Web"
        },
        {
            "url": "https://localhost:8666",
            "type": "Web"
        },
        {
            "url": "https://localhost:44394/",
            "type": "InstalledClient"
        },
        {
            "url": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/nativeclient",
            "type": "InstalledClient"
        },
        {
            "url": "https://localhost",
            "type": "Web"
        },
        {
            "url": "https://localhost:44394/signin-oidc",
            "type": "Web"
        },
        {
            "url": "https://localhost:44394",
            "type": "Web"
        }
    ],
    "requiredResourceAccess": [
        {
            "resourceAppId": "28xxxx12",
            "resourceAccess": [
                {
                    "id": "98xxxx5a",
                    "type": "Scope"
                },
                {
                    "id": "20xxxx7a",
                    "type": "Scope"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "resourceAppId": "0fxxxxa0",
            "resourceAccess": [
                {
                    "id": "1fxxx6a",
                    "type": "Scope"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "resourceAppId": "00xxx00",
            "resourceAccess": [
                {
                    "id": "18xxx10",
                    "type": "Scope"
                },
                {
                    "id": "3bxxxd5",
                    "type": "Scope"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "resourceAppId": "00xxx00",
            "resourceAccess": [
                {
                    "id": "64xxxd0",
                    "type": "Scope"
                },
                {
                    "id": "74xxx82",
                    "type": "Scope"
                },
                {
                    "id": "37xxx6e",
                    "type": "Scope"
                },
                {
                    "id": "14xxxc1",
                    "type": "Scope"
                },
                {
                    "id": "5cxxx65",
                    "type": "Scope"
                },
                {
                    "id": "57xxxca",
                    "type": "Scope"
                },
                {
                    "id": "02xxx73",
                    "type": "Scope"
                },
                {
                    "id": "e1xxxx3d",
                    "type": "Scope"
                },
                {
                    "id": "b4xxx4c",
                    "type": "Scope"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "samlMetadataUrl": null,
    "signInUrl": null,
    "signInAudience": "AzureADandPersonalMicrosoftAccount",
    "tags": [],
    "tokenEncryptionKeyId": null
}
```

And here is the manifest for PapayeeClient

```
{
    "id": "59xxxxe9",
    "acceptMappedClaims": null,
    "accessTokenAcceptedVersion": 2,
    "addIns": [],
    "allowPublicClient": null,
    "appId": "02xxx60",
    "appRoles": [],
    "oauth2AllowUrlPathMatching": false,
    "createdDateTime": "2020-04-13T22:34:14Z",
    "groupMembershipClaims": null,
    "identifierUris": [],
    "informationalUrls": {
        "termsOfService": null,
        "support": null,
        "privacy": null,
        "marketing": null
    },
    "keyCredentials": [],
    "knownClientApplications": [],
    "logoUrl": null,
    "logoutUrl": null,
    "name": "PapayeeClient",
    "oauth2AllowIdTokenImplicitFlow": true,
    "oauth2AllowImplicitFlow": true,
    "oauth2Permissions": [],
    "oauth2RequirePostResponse": false,
    "optionalClaims": null,
    "orgRestrictions": [],
    "parentalControlSettings": {
        "countriesBlockedForMinors": [],
        "legalAgeGroupRule": "Allow"
    },
    "passwordCredentials": [],
    "preAuthorizedApplications": [],
    "publisherDomain": "papayee008.onmicrosoft.com",
    "replyUrlsWithType": [
        {
            "url": "https://localhost:3000/",
            "type": "Web"
        },
        {
            "url": "https://localhost:8080/",
            "type": "Web"
        }
    ],
    "requiredResourceAccess": [
        {
            "resourceAppId": "28xxx12",
            "resourceAccess": [
                {
                    "id": "98xxx5a",
                    "type": "Scope"
                },
                {
                    "id": "20xxx7a",
                    "type": "Scope"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "resourceAppId": "00xxx00",
            "resourceAccess": [
                {
                    "id": "64xxxd0",
                    "type": "Scope"
                },
                {
                    "id": "74xxx82",
                    "type": "Scope"
                },
                {
                    "id": "37xxxx6e",
                    "type": "Scope"
                },
                {
                    "id": "14xxxc1",
                    "type": "Scope"
                },
                {
                    "id": "57xxxxca",
                    "type": "Scope"
                },
                {
                    "id": "02xxx73",
                    "type": "Scope"
                },
                {
                    "id": "e1xxxxx3d",
                    "type": "Scope"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "samlMetadataUrl": null,
    "signInUrl": null,
    "signInAudience": "AzureADandPersonalMicrosoftAccount",
    "tags": [],
    "tokenEncryptionKeyId": null
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your architecture is totally correct. Your scenario is **the client end** call your **webapi server**->webapi server call **Microsoft Graph API**.

Here are the samples which would be helpful in your project:

[A memo on how to implement Azure AD authentication using React and .NET Core](https://github.com/Odonno/azuread-react-dotnet-core-example)

[Call a downstream web API (Microsoft Graph) from a web API secured with the Microsoft identity platform (Azure Active Directory) using the On-Behalf-Of flow](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-aspnet-webapi-onbehalfof)

Comment: hi @TonyJu thank you so much for your help. I have tried the 1st example you provided and when i ran the React frontend, it always returns "Not authenticated". I will update my question to include what I have tried and the reactjs webapp

Comment: @Franva, I'm working on a similar architecture, SPA --> Web API --> Graph API. I was able to pass the authentication once I enabled CORS policy. My SPA and Web Api projects were using different ports causing Authorization header to be null in Web Api project. Once I enabled Cors, Authorization header was populated and I was able to call the web API. Currently, still struggling with user consent for Web API part. But, that's a different issue.